# Table Normalization, Attributes that have no dependencies

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, database-normalization, 3nf

Hi this is my first time posting so sorry if formatting is bad.

I have a question regarding normalization, I came across a problem in homework and I am having issues finding any information on it. This is not in a specific database language but we are working with sql.

I am giving a table like **T( A,B,C,D,E,F,G)**
and we are given the following dependencies **A+B----> C; A----> D, E; D---->E**

we are then asked to give the primary keys followed by a 2NF and 3NF

this was my answer originally
for 2nf **(A, B, C); (A, D, E)**
and 3nf **(A, B, C); (A, D, E); (D, E)** with primary keys being **A and B**

I then noticed the table contained two attributes with no relation **F and G**
now this is where I am having trouble, would these be considered candidate keys or are they dropped in a 2nf or 3nf for possible redundancy? Since we aren't given actual data it is hard for me to understand why a table would have two attributes that have no relation to a primary key.

Thanks

Comment: F and G must be part of every candidate key, so in your example the (only) candidate key is ABFG.

Comment: Ok thats what I was thinking, so would we represent the table in a 2 or 3nf as its own table? similar to how I have above with (A,B,C);(A,D,E) (F) (G)? If so Thanks I understand

Comment: A decomposition both in 2nf and 3nf is (ABC), (AD), (DE), (ABFG).

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS You're not doing what you were told, eg the definition of CK refers to all attributes.